# Assigning callback function in C++

Tags: c++, callback, theory

This question is somewhere between theoretical and practical.

I have a C file (let's call it fileA.c and fileA.h)

fileA.h defines a struct as such:

```
typedef struct
{
    /** Callback function which is called upon an event occurrence */
    void (*FileAcb)(MyEvent event, uint8 val);
} MyStruct;
```

In fileB.cpp and fileB.h, I am trying to assign the callback function to it like this.

FileB.h

```
class FileB
{
    public:
        static void Callback(MyEvent event, uint8 val);
    protected:
        /**Protected members */
    private:
        /**Private members */
        MyStruct myStruct;
};
```

FileB.cpp

```
bool FileB::Start()
{
    myStruct.FileAcb= FileB::Callback;

    return true;
}

void FileB::Callback(MyEvent event, uint8 val)
{
    //do some stuff here.
}
```

And this works. However, I'm looking for a way to write this line:

```
myStruct.FileAcb= FileB::Callback;
```

in a way that allows my FileB::Callback function **to NOT be static**. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: "I have a C file (let's call it fileA.c and fileA.h)" - Depending on whether you count headers as C files (in the sense of "the language C") or not, that either makes two C files or one is not relevant. Anyway, that is not C!

Comment: @Olaf I guess in this situation, I gave extraneous info. Ultimately, all I care about is the typedef struct in FileA.h

Comment: Did you search the web about your question? ^^ https://www.google.de/search?q=cpp+Callback+function+to+NOT+be+static.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_MiwVtqYF4fcO6f4s8gM

Comment: This is C++, so it is not just a compound datatype, but a class. In general, programming C-style in C++ is pretty bad style. Most higher-level features of a language exist to make the code more readable and enhance quality. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve that?

Not directly.
The traditional C-style way to do this is to provide a `void*` argument which points to your object, and a little forwarding function:

```
struct CallbackWithData
{
    void *closure;
    void (*callback)(void *closure, MyEvent event, uint8 val);
};

void ForwardToFileB(void *closure, MyEvent event, uint8 val)
{
    FileB *target = (FileB *)closure;
    target->Callback(event, val);
}
```

Even in non-OO-style C, it's traditional to provide this kind of argument to callback functions, so they have somewhere to keep any state they might need.

The C++-like way to do this would be to use `std::function<void(MyEvent,uint8_t)>` instead of a raw pointer.